# SUPEE-8788 Issue on Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, security, patches, supee-8788

After installing SUPEE-8788 on Magento 1.8, a file is created in a**pp/code/local/Mage/Core/functions.php.**
Why Mage file is here instead of **app/code/core** ?

Answer (score 1):

This is your custom file. Patch changes only `app/code/core/Mage/Core/function.php file`. You could leave your local function file in case you have **PHP >= 5.6** otherwise copy method `hash_equal` into your local `function.php`

Comment: I hadn't created it. It appears after installation of SUPEE-8788

Comment: `
grep 'functions.php' PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.8.0.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-33-04.sh
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php`

Comment: Whats that ? Should I run that command on shell to see effects ??